# How to apply json-patch to plain json in .net core?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json-patch

[JsonPatchDocument.Apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.jsonpatch.jsonpatchdocument?view=aspnetcore-3.0) method works on an object graph, but instead I want to apply a json patch to plain json.

For example, suppose I have this json:

```
{ "name": "JSON Patch", "text": "OLD" }
```

How can I apply a patch like this with C#?

```
[ { "op": "replace", "path": "/text", "value": "NEW VALUE" } ]
```

How is this done using C# and .NET core?

Comment: so you're using asp.net core for the patch?

Comment: Thanks for your input. No, in this scenario, it is a Xamarin Forms client that receives a json patch (from an api service) and applies it to a local stored document.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a snippet of code which applies patch:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json="{ \"name\": \"JSON Patch\", \"text\": \"OLD\" }";
        var jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        var operationStrings = "[ { \"op\": \"replace\", \"path\": \"/text\", \"value\": \"NEW VALUE\" } ] ";
        var ops = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.Operations.Operation>>(operationStrings);
        
        var patchDocument = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.JsonPatchDocument(ops, new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver());
        
        patchDocument.ApplyTo(jsonObj);
        Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj));
    }
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful to me today, thank you!